# Pass variable from Google maps to jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When someone clicks a marker on Google Maps, I want to use the var currMarker (the ID of the marker) in jQuery.

Any idea how to achieve this? The currMarker alert works. Now I need to pass it to jQuery.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

    var currMarker = markers[i][4];
    alert(currMarker);

    }
})(marker, i));
```

--update---

I want to use it in jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax ({
type: "POST",
url: "/url",
data: "currMarker="+currMarker, etc.
```

Comment: In what way do you want to pass it to jQuery? As a variable or to a function?

Comment: As a variable would be best. I need it to pass it to an AJAX datastring. The answers below aren't doing the trick yet :)

Comment: Can you show an example of how you want it?

Comment: Well, if you can show me how I can alert the 'var currMarker' in jQuery instead of javascript it would make me very happy!

Comment: jQuery doesn't have `alert`. JavaScript does. I really don't understand what you want it to do. You want to pass it to an AJAX datastring? Can you show how you would do that.

Comment: I updated the question with the ajax use

Comment: Seems like Johans answer is what you want isn't it?

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was reading it completely teh wrong way. Sorry!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're asking for IMO, but maybe something like this?

```
...
var currMarker = markers[i][4];
$(document).data({ currMarker: currMarker });
...
```

And somewhere else access it like

```
var currMarker = $(document).data('currMarker');
if(currMarker)
    console.log(currMarker);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by changing it to **`global`** variable.  *From your code it seems you're iterating the values,* so my suggestion is to change `currMarker` as `array` literal like

```
var currMarker= []; // declare it as array literal 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    currMarker.push(markers[i][4]); push each values to currMarker
    alert(currMarker);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

Comment: Isn't it already in the global scope? OP is using the array `markers`.